# Trigger - is it necessary BEGIN / COMMIT TRAN

Tags: sql-server, triggers, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2014

I want to make INSTEAD OF trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[DeleteCompany]
ON [dbo].[Company]
 INSTEAD OF DELETE
  AS 
  DECLARE @CompanyID int
  SELECT @CompanyID = deleted.CompanyID FROM deleted

  BEGIN TRAN
  DELETE FROM Project WHERE CompanyID = @CompanyID
  DELETE FROM CompanyPerson WHERE CompanyID = @CompanyID
  UPDATE PersonCompany SET CompanyID = null WHERE CompanyID = @CompanyID

  DELETE [Company]
     FROM DELETED D
     INNER JOIN [Company] T ON T.CompanyID = D.CompanyID
  COMMIT TRAN
```

So, I can be sure, that these actions is one atomic action. But it make sense or TRIGGER always execute inside transaction?

Also, what happens if company will be deleted inside another TRIGGER like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[DeleteSecurityLevel]
ON [dbo].[SecurityLevel]
 INSTEAD OF DELETE
  AS 
  DECLARE @SecurityLevelID int
  SELECT @SecurityLevelID = deleted.SecurityLevelID FROM deleted

  BEGIN TRAN
  DELETE FROM Company WHERE SecurityLevelId = @SecurityLevelID
  DELETE FROM CompanyRole WHERE SecurityLevelId = @SecurityLevelID
  ....

  DELETE SecurityLevel
     FROM DELETED D
     INNER JOIN SecurityLevel T ON T.SecurityLevelID = D.SecurityLevelID
  COMMIT TRAN
```

so, trigger DeleteSecurityLevel is deleting Company and call DeleteCompany trigger. It would be in one transaction if each trigger has BEGIN/COMMIT TRAM ? if each trigger does not have it?

PS. I can't set "CASCADE DELETE" because DB has some relationships like it:

[image]

so, try to set CASCADE DELETE will throw error like it:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Persons_Areas' on table
>   'Persons' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON
>   DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous
>   errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All DML statements are executed within a transaction.  The DML within the trigger will use the transaction context of the statement that fired the trigger so all modifications, inside the trigger and out, are a single atomic operation.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need explicit transactions inside the trigger, they share the same transaction workspace and the batch inside the trigger and the operation invoking it either commit together or rollback together

Answer (score 0):

A trigger always executes in the context of a transaction - every DML statement operates within a transaction. This is normally hidden from view by the fact that Implicit Transactions are set to commit automatically in SQL Server.
If you issue a rollback from within a trigger, this will (as always with rollback) rollback all transactions, whether nested or not.
In general, you wouldn't commit within a trigger, unless (as in your commented out example) you're opening a nested transaction explicitly.
If there are other aspects to your question, I'm unable to work out what they are from your posted example. Although I'm always a fan of people posting actual SQL when asking SQL questions, sometimes a little commentary, or a bullet-point list of actual questions can help.